# What is the actual width of default table borders?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

When you use a `table` tag and add `border="1"`, what is the actual value of that border? It's not 1 pixel because when I try to replicate it's much thinner than the border=1 version. So:

`"border=1"` is a thicker line

`style="border:1px solid #000"` is a thinner line

I am trying to replicate it but can't find a match.

EDIT: I need to do this inline as there will not be a style sheet. Please let me know if this can be done inline at all.

Comment: This is a crazy one... Have a look at the dupe. `:D`

Comment: This is likely browser specific, why does it matter? `border` is depreciated cant you just use CSS?

Comment: Thanks. I can't use a style sheet for this one. I have to work inline so it's a little more complicated.

Comment: I'm guessing it's not strictly true that you have to work "inline".  While you may not be able to add an external CSS file, I'm guessing that you could inject a CSS `style` block into the page(s) somewhere, and set yourself free from the insanity of maintaining _actual inline styles_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between the `border` attribute and the `style` attribute is that the former also gives borders to the cells inside, while the latter doesn't.

So that got me thinking, and my guess is that you haven't given all the information needed to replicate the problem. So please correct me if I'm wrong, but I am assuming that you also had `cellspacing="0"` on the table, and in the attempted styled version, no `style` attribute on the table cells.

```html
<table border="1" cellspacing="0">
<tr><td>with border attr</td></tr>
</table>

<br>

<table style="border:1px solid #000">
<tr><td>with style props</td></tr>
</table>
```

So in the top table, the table has a 1px border, and the cell inside also does. And there you have it, 2px border in total.

This situation can be emulated using styles; you just need some more styles.

```html
<table border="1" cellspacing="0"> <!-- same as above -->
<tr><td>with border attr</td></tr>
</table>

<br>

<table style="border:1px outset #000; border-spacing:0">
<tr><td style="border:1px inset #000">with style props</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not specify the value of border attribute, it is taken as zero by default.
You can get more information in tech talk of beanstalk learning

Comment: While it's great you want to help, this doesn't really answer the question.  Further, the notion of going off-site ("beanstalk learning"), further compounded by no link, is not really the "Stackoverflow Way".  You should copy the relevant bits here, and use a link off-site to _support_ your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because

```
border=20
```

in HTML is equivalent to

```
border:20px outset #7F7F7F;
```

in CSS.

Try the code below and you will understand.
"border" in HTML draws a gray border at the top and left and almost black at the bottom and right.

HTML border is not a solid black border. Even for border = 1 in HTML, if you zoom in on the browser a lot you will see that the border is not solid or black. It's a lighter and darker gray like I told you above.

Attention # 7F7F7F is the only chrome equivalent on your PC. There are no equivalent shades of gray for Firefox. Or you can replace border = 20 with

```
border-top:20px solid #c0c0c0;
border-left:20px solid #c0c0c0;
border-right:20px solid #505050;
border-bottom:20px solid #505050;
```

I don't know if I hit the correct color values.

Below is the code to see that border=20 does not draw a solid black border.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#tabela1 th, td {
   border: 1px solid black;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<table style="width:100%" border=20 cellspacing=30 cellpadding=10>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br><br>

<table id="tabela1" style="width:100%; border:20px outset #7F7F7F;" cellspacing=30 cellpadding=10>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Taken from: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp

```
display: table;
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 2px;
border-color: gray;
```

Comment: HTML border draws a light gray border at the top and left and a dark gray border at the bottom and right. The default css gray is the same everywhere. Try     <table border=20><tr><td>test</td></tr></table>